# Draw two groups of multiple vertical lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to drew the two groups such as `a1, a2` and `b1, b2` of vertical lines in ggplot using the following `r` functions.

```
myline = data.frame(vv = c(a1 = 25, a2 = 28, b1 = 52, b2 = 53))


set.seed(100)
d = data.frame(y = c(rnorm(100,5,1), rnorm(100, 2,4)), x = 1:200)
ggplot(data = d) + geom_line(aes(x, y), color = "steelblue") + 
  geom_vline(data = myline, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(vv)), col= 'red', size = 0.8)
```

I am trying to separate the `a` and `b` groups in different colors. How can I do that? Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the vertical lines of different colors, use `vv` as the color in the call to `geom_vline`. Then set the colors of choice with `scale_color_manual`.
Note also that there is no need for `as.numeric(vv)` when setting the value for the `xintercept` aesthetic, `str(myline)` will show `vv` already is numeric.

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line(color = "steelblue") + 
  geom_vline(data = myline, 
             aes(xintercept = vv, color = factor(vv)),
             size = 0.4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("coral", "coral4", "orange", "orange4"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after?

```
library("dplyr")

myline = data.frame(vv = c(25, 28, 52, 53),
                    xx = c("a1", "a2", "b1", "b2"))

myline <- as_tibble(myline) %>%
  mutate(group = substr(xx,1,1))

set.seed(100)
d = data.frame(y = c(rnorm(100,5,1), rnorm(100, 2,4)), x = 1:200)

ggplot(data = d) + geom_line(aes(x, y), color = "steelblue") + 
  geom_vline(data = myline, aes(xintercept=as.numeric(vv), col=group), size = 0.8)
```